# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ if $x_{n+1}=\frac{k+x_n}{1+x_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

## Problem

Assume that
$x_{n+1}=\dfrac{k+x_n}{1+x_n},k>1,x_1 \geq 0.$

1) Prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ is absolutely convergent.

2) Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)$.

## Attempt

By induction, we can obtain $x_n\geq0$, namely $1+x_n\geq 1$. Thus $$x_{n+1}=\frac{k+x_n}{1+x_n}=\frac{1+x_n+(k-1)}{1+x_n}=1+\frac{k-1}{1+x_n}\leq 1+(k-1)=k.$$

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{k+x}{1+x}, x \in [0,k].$$
We obtain
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-k}{(1+x)^2}.$$
Therefore
$$|f'(k)|\leq k-1.$$
But this can not satisfy the condition such that **the contraction mapping principle** holds.

Comment: Note the series is telescopic so the limit is basically the limit of $x_n$. If it exists then $\ell(1+\ell)=k+\ell\iff \ell^2=k$. So maybe you can try evaluating $y_n=x_n^2-k$.

Comment: This is a spiral convergence, so show $x_{2n}$ an $x_{2n+1}$ are adjacent sequences by studying $f(x)-\ell$ and $f(f(x))-x$. See for $k=2$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522679/showing-the-convergence-of-the-the-following-recursively-defined-sequence/2522776#2522776

Comment: I have proved that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n =\sqrt{k}$. How to prove 1)?

Comment: Use partial sums

Answer (score 1):

#### Here's my solution. Please check.

It's obvious that，if $0\leq x_n<\sqrt{k}$，then $x_{n+1}>\sqrt{k}$；if $x_n>\sqrt{k}$，then $0\leq x_{n+1}<\sqrt{k}$；if $x_n=\sqrt{k}$，then $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{k}$. Thus, by induction, we obtain

1）if $0\leq x_1<\sqrt{k}$，then $\forall n:x_{2n}>\sqrt{k},0\leq x_{2n+1}<\sqrt{k}$；

2）if $x_1>\sqrt{k}$，then $\forall n:0\leq x_{2n}<\sqrt{k},x_{2n+1}>\sqrt{k}$；

3）if $x_1=\sqrt{k}$，then $\forall n: x_n \equiv \sqrt{k}$.

When $1)$ holds，then
$$x_{2n+1}-x_{2n-1}=\frac{2k+(k+1)x_{2n-1}}{k+1+2x_{2n-1}}-x_{2n-1}=\frac{2(k-x_{2n-1}^2)}{k+2x_{2n-1}+1}>0,$$
and
$$x_{2n+2}-x_{2n}=\frac{2k+(k+1)x_{2n}}{k+1+2x_{2n}}-x_{2n}=\frac{2(k-x_{2n}^2)}{k+2x_{2n}+1}<0,$$
which implies the subsequence $\{x_{2n-1}\}$ is increasing and upward bounded, and the one $\{x_{2n}\}$ is decreasing and downward bounded. Therefore, both of them are convergent. Denote the limit of them as $a,b$ respectively. Taking the limits of the equalities
$$ x_{2n+1}=\frac{2k+(k+1)x_{2n-1}}{k+1+2x_{2n-1}},~~~x_{2n+2}=\frac{2k+(k+1)x_{2n}}{k+1+2x_{2n}},$$
we obtain
$$a=\frac{2k+(k+1)a}{k+1+2a},~~~b=\frac{2k+(k+1)b}{k+1+2b}.$$
Solve to get
$$a=\sqrt{k},b=\sqrt{k}.$$
This shows that $\{x_{2n-1}\}$ and $\{x_{2n}\}$ converges to the same limit. Thus, $\{x_n\}$ converges to it as well, namely $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}x_n=\sqrt{k}.\tag{*}$$

Moreover, if $2)$ holds, the reasoning is similar；if $3)$ holds，it's a trivial case. It follows that $(*)$ holds for all cases.

Now, consider $$f(x)=\frac{k+x}{1+x},(x\geq 0,k>1).$$
We have $$|f'(x)|=\frac{k-1}{(1+x)^2},$$
which is decreasing over $[0,+\infty)$. Thus
$$\forall x \in I:= (\sqrt{k}-1,\sqrt{k}+1):|f'(x)|<|f'(\sqrt{k}-1)|=1-\frac{1}{k}<1.$$
Denote $|f'(\sqrt{k}-1)|=p$. Since $x_n \to \sqrt{k}(n \to \infty)$， then $$\exists N \in \mathbb{N},\forall n>N:|x_n-\sqrt{k}|<1,$$ namely
$$x_{N+1},x_{N+2},\cdots \in I.$$
By Lagrange's MVT，for all $q=1,2,\cdots$, it holds that
\begin{align*}
|x_{N+q+2}-x_{N+q+1}|&=|f(x_{N+q+1})-f(x_{N+q})|\\&=|f'(\xi)||x_{N+q+1}-x_{N+q}|\\
&<p|x_{N+q+1}-x_{N+q}|.
\end{align*}
By induction, we have
$$|x_{N+q+2}-x_{N+q+1}|<p^q|x_{N+2}-x_{N+1}|.$$
Therefore， for a large sufficiently $n$，
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k+1}-x_k|&=\sum_{k=1}^{N}|x_{k+1}-x_k|+\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}|x_{k+1}-x_k|\\
&<\sum_{k=1}^{N}|x_{k+1}-x_k|+(1+p+p^2+\cdots+p^{n-N-1})|x_{N+2}-x_{N+1}|\\
&<\sum_{k=1}^{N}|x_{k+1}-x_k|+\frac{1}{1-p}|x_{N+2}-x_{N+1}|\\
&<+\infty,
\end{align*}
which shows the partial sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k+1}-x_k|$ is bounded.  Thus $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_{k+1}-x_k|$ is convergent. As a result,$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(x_{k+1}-x_k)$ is abosolutely convergent， which shows that $(1)$ holds.

Meanwhile，$(2)$ is simple，since
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_{k+1}-x_k)=\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_{n+1}-x_1)=\sqrt{k}-x_1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f\circ f$. It has bounded image (as $f$ has) and is increasing. It follows that the subsequences $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n-1})$ are convergent. Their limit is $\sqrt{k}$ (as pointed out in the comments), so $(x_n)$ converges to $\sqrt{k}$.

Comment: I have proved that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n =\sqrt{k}$. How to prove 1)?