# Identify a number series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

What is this series?
What is its analytical solution?

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{A+Bx_{n}}{C+Dx_{n}}$$

This can also be written as:

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{B}{D}+\frac{A-\frac{BC}{D}}{C+Dx_{n}}$$

Comment: Are you looking for the limit $n\to \infty$?

Comment: I'd say it will very much depend on the coefficients, you can have no fixed points or 1 or 2, repulsive or attractive, some converging in staircase ($x_n$ monotonous) other in spiral ($x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ monotonous). Here are some specific examples I treated, notice the technique is similar. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2624102/399263, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2522776/399263, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3823634/399263.

Comment: No actually I was hoping for an analytical solution

Comment: Hint, this is a [Moebius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) and so can be represented by a matrix. Then you can generate iterates by considering powers of the matrix, we can in turn be found by diagonalizing.

Comment: @Jair yep, my second link has a showcase of that method by Robert Israel.

Comment: @zwim I'd like to get your name and give credit for helping me out, I am writing a paper.

Comment: @JairTaylor I'd like to get your name and give credit for helping me out, I am writing a paper.

Comment: @ParsaRahimi Thank you but it's really not necessary, this is a well-known and standard technique. In any case this is my real name.

Answer (score 1):

In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885418/finding-the-closed-form-of-a-recursive-sequence/3885693#3885693), I detailed the steps for solving a first-order rational difference equation such as
$${ x_{n+1} = \frac{a+m\,x_n }{b+x_n } }$$

So, for your case, let $a=\frac AD$, $m=\frac BD$ and $b=\frac CD$